# height 100% doesn't work under column flexbox ancestor

Tags: css

```css
.layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  min-height: 100vh;
}

.body {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  Header
  <div class="body">
    Body
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
  Footer
</div>
```

- Why doesn't `div.content` occupy 100% of window?
- Is there a way to make `div.content` span 100% vertically while having `div.layout` flexbox?
- If there isn't, how can I make it while having this header-body-footer structure?

#### Edit 1

- `div.body` should follow default display property. I can't make it flexbox.

Comment: Percentage height does not work with min-height. It requires a determined parent height to function.

Comment: *div.body should follow default display property. I can't make it flexbox.* --> then what you want is not possible

Comment: the simpliest solution is to use `display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: auto 1fr;` on body element

Answer (score 1):

```css
.layout {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.body {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background-color: #a0a0a0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  Header
  <div class="body">
    Body
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
  Footer
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but I forgot to mention that I can't customize `div.layout` or `div.body` to have any other display property.

Answer (score 0):

```
.layout {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100vh;
    }
```

edit div.latout code -> min-height change height